# Can I specify a location of a text box and move it down without top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been developing a website using bootstrap-4 and I am using a container class (responsive class on bootstrap) on this title inside of my . The only problem I have is that my navbar has half transparency and it is going to the top of the page and if you click on the image you see a white box and I would like the text to be restricted to that size in those borders lines.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnI25.png)
The reason I would not like to use top or bottom is that it messes up with my responsiveness on mobile devices etc.

I also believe that one of the reasons this is getting issues is because of my header.

Here is some code

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>"We specialise in interiors and upholstery for automobiles</h2>
    <p>supercars, classic cars, modern cars and motorbikes."</p>
  </div
```

.

Here is my css for the header

```
  height: 30vh;
  position: static;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://i.gyazo.com/7802614bc17ae16529be7d3628cd3552.png";
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on any of the `display` properties that the `.container` class would use in Bootstrap as I don't use it. But adding `display: flex;` to `.container` and using flexbox will do the trick.

CSS Code:

```
header {
  /* change height accordingly  */
  height: 30vh;
  position: static;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image:url("https://i.gyazo.com/7802614bc17ae16529be7d3628cd3552.png");
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

Codepen Link
https://codepen.io/oliverheward/pen/jOEvPby

Better browser support:

```
header {
  /* change height accordingly  */
  height: 30vh;
  position: static;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image:url("https://i.gyazo.com/7802614bc17ae16529be7d3628cd3552.png");
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: column nowrap;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising Oliver,
I will change the text accordingly and hopefully this will sort this out, appreciate this a lot.

Comment: No worries bud, just send a reply or drop into a codepen and link over :)